# Geometry including semicircle and arc length

Tags: geometry, circles, arc-length

This is a question in the Princeton online test of GRE general book. I got it wrong, but even when I looked at the answer I find it difficult to understand how the answer is obtained. In the explanation given, how does if the new angle were $90^\circ$, Quantity $A$ become $\frac{1}{2}$? Wouldn't it be $\frac{\sqrt{2} r}{2r} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$?
Then I don't understand how it is concluded that it is less than $60^\circ$

[image]

Comment: The answer is right. The answering is stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the explanation is confusing, but the answer is right.  If arc $AB$ is shorter than both arc $AC$ and arc $BD$ (and those latter two are equal), then arc $AB$ must be less than $60$ degrees.  If we let the diameter $CD = 2$, then the length of the chord $AB$ must be less than $2 \sin (60/2) = 2 \sin 30 = 1$*.  Therefore $AB/CD < 1/2$, and the answer (B) is obtained.

*An explanation of this part: Construct the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AB}$.  This is a (vertical) diameter of the circle.  Since the arc $AB$ spans less than $60$ degrees, each half of that arc spans less than $30$ degrees.  But each half of the line segment $\overline{AB}$ is equal to the sine of half the arc, and is thus less than $\sin 30$.  The two halves (which is the entire line segment $\overline{AB}$) is thus less than twice that, or $2 \sin 30 = 1$.

Comment: Can you please explain how " the length of the chord $AB$ must be less than $2sin(60/2)=2sin30=1$" is obtained

Comment: @clarkson: Added as an edit.

Comment: Now I understand it. Thanks. However,in the expalnation given in the book, they say if the angle is $90^0$ then Quantity A becomes $ \frac{1}{2}$. I donot understand this. If the center is $O$, then by new angle does it mean, "AOB" ? Then since $AOB $is a right triangle with $AO=OB=1$ isn't AB=$\sqrt 2$

Comment: I don't really follow the explanation in the book, I'm afraid, so I can't really explain it on the whole.  Maybe they meant to write $60$ in both places, and somehow $90$ found its way in there.  Sometimes that happens.